# Extract Attributes from c# source code without Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, roslyn

I want to extract `custom attributes` from source code from different `.CS` files. I have list of files .

Scenario is that i have `Project A` which reads files of `Project B`. It has to extract all attributes used in `Project B`.

My question is that how can i do that without using `Reflection`. 
Reflection deals with assemblies but i have source code.

Using Roslyn would be over kill?

what approaches are there?

I had another option to Compile using `MSBuild` but for large scale projects it would not be feasable due to heavy dependencies. and it seems not a good way to build application and then going for its assemblies

i just want to have some sort of thing that tells me what attribute was on what class and possible a UML diagram of relations of that classes.

Please give your suggestions

Comment: Can you provide some examples?  It may be possible with regex if your code layout is fairly consistent.  But there's nothing wrong with using reflection even if you have the source code...it's fairly easy and efficient.

Comment: How about something like http://irony.codeplex.com/ or another code parser to extract the results?

Comment: how can you use reflection........

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  You can dig out an attribute by parsing the source code.  But what you *don't know* is what the attribute actually *means*.  You'll get [Foo], what does it do?  It requires *running* the code that looks for the attribute and does something with it.

Comment: @AfnanBashir: You would still have to *build* the source code, and know which types you want to reflect into rather than which source files.  But with reflection, you'll have easy access to semantic information about the code, and all the attributes.

Comment: I Agree it is way much better then Regex or parsers.......What should he use then? MSBuild ...............?

Answer (score 3):

You could use NRefactory: https://github.com/icsharpcode/nrefactory (also available as a NuGet package)